# Application gets closed when terminal is closed, how to stop this?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have a expect script which is like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/firefox https://www.google.com/
```

soon as i the script is finished..
the terminal closes itself, which is no problem for me.

but it also closes the firefox browser that it opened.

i need the browser to remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nohup` to prevent child processes from being killed when the terminal closes.

```
spawn nohup /usr/bin/firefox https://www.google.com/
```

I assume there's more to the script, since there's no need to use Expect just to start firefox.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/firefox https://www.google.com/ \&
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/firefox https://www.google.com/ "&"
```